# Visual Studio 2017 double items in menu

Tags: visual-studio

I've just run fresh installation of VS 2017 and my menu looks like this:

[image]

I found some solutions about this issue for older versions of VS, but nothing works for me. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: reinstall helped

Comment: Same problem. But not a fresh install... The funny thing is that after an extension update the menu was fixed. I do not think it must be a specific extension. For me it was: Power Shell Tools for Visual Studio.